# How to collect addresses from different tbls into one without breaking referential integrity SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-structures

I've been dealing with data migration out of ancient AS400 piece by piece through linked server connection and I'm having hard time figuring out the best way to structure everything into more or less decent way. I'm joining multiple tables into views to get a piece of data I'm looking for and then creating tables out of that views.

I have tables that have information about different parties like attorney, commissioner, claimant (id, names, contact info etc). Those tables also contain addresses of corresponding party.

What I would like to do is to have only one Address table and collect all of the addresses in  there but I'm having hard time keeping up with referential integrity since each table has over 1,5 million records.

What would be the right way do achieve that?

Examples of columns in some tables:

- Claimant (Id, ClaimNo, First/LastName, Phone, email, Street, City, State, Zip)
- Attorney (AttCode, First/LastName, FirmId, Phone, email, Street, City, State, Zip)
- Insurer (InsCode, Name, PolicyNo, Phone, email, Street, City, State, Zip) etc

Comment: This is really broad as it is. What is breaking the referential integrity to start with? inserting data into a new table doesn't break it; so tehre's steps we don't have here.

Comment: The number of rows is not relevant in keeping referential integrity. There are a number of data modeling patterns you could use. Sample SQL Server databases like Adventureworks and WideWorldImporters show a couple of examples.

Comment: I suggest you build a replica out of the AS400 with an identical schema. Then do your fiddling after that. Don't do piecemeal transformations out of source systems. just replicate them first them do the transformations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this doesn't seem hard:

```
create table addresses (
    address_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    street varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state varchar(255),
    zip varchar(10)
);
```

(The above assumes US addresses.)

```
insert into addresses (address)
    select street, city, state, zip 
    from claimant
    union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
    select street, city, state, zip 
    from attorney
    union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
    select street, city, state, zip 
    from insurer;
```

You now have a table of unique addresses.  When you go to load into your new tables, you can `join` to match the values:

```
insert into new_insurers ( . . ., addressid)
    select . . ., a.addressid
    from insurer i left join
         addresses a
         on i.street = a.street and
            i.city = a.city and
            i.state = a.state and
            i.zip = a.zip;
```

You may have to take additional care if any of the value are `NULL`, but this should give you the general idea.